# How do you bypass locked for editing message by opening an Excel file ReadOnly?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have a macro to open a file which I would like to run using VBS.

It loads the macro but gets stuck on a "ABC is locked for editing" message.

I would need to bypass **any** additional locked for editing messages with **Read Only**. If I make the application visible, it will show the message and I click on "Read Only" and it will run ok.

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlFile
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Application.Visible = True
xlApp.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set xlFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\PATH\CDRsyslog.txt", 0, True)
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\SYSCDR.xlsm", 0, True)

xlFile.ReadOnlyRecommended = True
xlBook.ReadOnlyRecommended = True

xlApp.Run "CDRMACRO.CDRMACRO"

xlBook.Close
xlFile.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

I've tried (changes implemented above)

```
Set xlFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\FILEPATHANDNAMEHERE", 0, True)
```

I have also tried to change the macro, but I reverted the changes since the macro runs just fine without changes.

Somewhere I need to tell the VBS to simply open any other files as read-only and thereby bypass further "locked for editing" messages.

Comment: so the problem exists when the `CDRMACRO` tries to open files that you have set to open as `ReadOnly` when run from the vbscript?

Comment: Does it have links to external workbooks?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment about the ReadOnly = True part; the sentence with "ambiguous" in it. I tried and it works perfectly. What's wrong with it?

Comment: ok I made the changes adding the xlFile line. It still comes up with the "locked for editing" message although I've added as read only

Comment: also, my macro has the following lines :
`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`
`Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False`
`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my macro by adding the readonly :

```
Workbooks.Open fileName:="\\PATH\CDRsyslog.txt", ReadOnly:=True
```

I removed this from the VBS file :

```
Set xlFile = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\FILEPATHANDNAMEHERE", 0, True)
```